# How to sort by main item first then sub items in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains main product and it's sub products like the following

[image]

And I want to sort the table first the main product and then all it's sub products like the following image.

[image]

I can do this with code but I want to fetch the sorted data using SQL query, Please help.

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: See about JOINs, and COALESCE, say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `main_product_id` column value is blank,  then we can consider it as a `main_product` and it has to come first for that group.

**Query**

```
select t.`product_id`, t.`main_product_id` from(
    select `product_id`, `main_product_id`, 
    case when coalesce(trim(`mp_id`), '') = '' then `product_id` 
    else `main_product_id` end as `main_product_id_2`
    from `your_table_name`
) t
order by `main_product_id_2`, 
case when coalesce(trim(t.`main_product_id`), '') = '' then 1 else 2 end,
t.`product_id`;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/QTTD45508)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this if `main_product_id` is `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
ORDER BY COALESCE(main_product_id, product_id) ASC, 
         (CASE WHEN main_product_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC, 
         product_id ASC
```

If it's `''`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN main_product_id = '' THEN product_id ELSE main_product_id END) ASC, 
         (CASE WHEN main_product_id = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC,
         product_id ASC
```

The Order Bys:

1. always get the `main_product_id`, to "group" them.
2. a sorting help, to get the main_product_id on top
3. sort by `product_id` (or whatever you want the sub-products to be sorted)